# Rspec testing in ruby mine always returns false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I have a class User as follows

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :session
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
  has_and_belongs_to_many :replies

  attr_accessor :clear_text_password;

  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :username
  validates :clear_text_password, :presence => true, :length => {:minimum => 6}
  validates_confirmation_of :clear_text_password

  validates_presence_of :e_mail
  validates_uniqueness_of :e_mail

  def User.authenticate(name, password)
    if user = find_by_username(name)
      if user.password == encrypt_password(password)
        user

      end
    end
  end

end
```

Now, my rspec test file is as below

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec'
require 'rspec-rails'
require 'user'

describe User do
  describe "my first test" do
    it "should redirect if user is authenticated" do
      user = User.authenticate('abcd','abcdef')
      c=false
      if user
        c=true
      end
      c.should == true

    end
  end
end
```

The database table users has the username and password "abcd" and "abcdef" . but the test always fails. the method call always returns false. Please help!!

Comment: rspec runs against the test database and might be emptied before each test. Have you entered your test data in the 'development' or the 'test' database? A decent thing to do is to create the data in the test. If you want to have the same user for many tests just put it in a "before" method.

Comment: froderick's comment above is likely the solution to your issue. For the records don't use all that logic (if/else, `c=false`), just use `User.authenticate('xxx', 'xxx').should_not be_nil`